# Drag and drop to an app in a remote desktop session

Tags: delphi, remote-desktop, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Some example code, that works in a regular (local) session:

```
constructor TForm1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_COPYGLOBALDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, True);
end;

destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, False);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetDropFilenames(const ADropHandle: HDROP);
var
  I, LFileCount, LLength: integer;
  LFilename: string;
begin
  LFileCount := DragQueryFile(ADropHandle, $FFFFFFFF, nil, 0);
  for I := 0 to LFileCount - 1 do
  begin
    LLength := DragQueryFile(ADropHandle, I, nil, 0) + 1;
    SetLength(LFilename, LLength);
    DragQueryFile(ADropHandle, I, PChar(LFilename), LLength);
    LLength := Pos(#0, LFileName);
    if LLength > 0 then
      LFilename := LFilename.Substring(0, LLength - 1);
    LogMemo.Lines.Add('Filename Copied To Clipboard: ' + LFilename);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
begin
  GetDropFilenames(Msg.Drop);
  Msg.Result := 0;
  inherited;
end;
```

i.e. dropping some files onto the app results in the filenames being added to the memo.

I want to be able to have the app running on a remote machine, and drag files from the local machine into the app in the remote desktop session. I just need it to operate via drag/drop, and have the names of the files accessible as per when it runs locally; what I actually do with the filenames isn't relevant.

Someone suggested that making the app run with elevated privileges would make it work, except that (for me), it does not.

[image]

The remote machine is running Windows Server 2019.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I don't know if this works over a remote session, but try implementing the `IDropTarget` interface and pass it to `RegisterDragDrop()`, instead of handling `WM_DROPFILES` (which is LONG deprecated anyway).

Comment: Does it even work natively? I mean can you drop a file through the shells of the machines, explorer to explorer?

Comment: As long as the API is concerned you are dropping files onto an application's window which is a RDP client, not a Delphi application. Specifically an "Output Painter Window" of an "OPContainerClass" class on my system. That's to say, the RDP client might or might not be interested in any files being dropped on. As I see it, this is  more of a terminal services question.

Comment: A RDP session and anything in it is not a drop target or source from the client.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz "Does it even work natively? I mean can you drop a file through the shells of the machines, explorer to explorer?". No, it doesn't, which leads me to believe it's something that needs to be configured, rather than something in code

Comment: Although this is from 4 years ago, it seems it is not possible at all: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f535dd31-4972-4f40-8105-fdaa2c5364c2/drag-and-drop?forum=winserverTS

Comment: This seems more like a question for https://superuser.com